# Why is a non-custom Angular pipe causing my build to not pass, yet all tests pass, and linting passes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jenkins, pipe

I am working on an Angular 4 project right now, and in it, I'm using the `NumberPipe`, which I don't even have to import for it to work fine because it comes from `CommonModule` as I understand.

I use the pipe in my template like so... Pretend `results` is a number in my component.

```
<p>{{ results | number : fractionSize }} Results</p>
```

The problem is, it causes my Jenkins build to fail... It says `Property 'fractionSize' does not exist on type 'AuctionsComponent'`

My question is, since I didn't have to import it to use it in my project, why then is it not available for my tests, and if it needs to be declared in a module, where, and why?

Here is a copy of the message from Jenkins...

```
13:54:11 Date: 2017-11-16T20:54:11.047Z
13:54:11 Hash: 17c7bbfe51457a0c0c2a
13:54:11 Time: 34993ms
13:54:11 chunk {0} styles.d1347092f22621d601cc.bundle.css (styles) 402 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
13:54:11 chunk {1} polyfills.3bc34265385d52184eab.bundle.js (polyfills) 86 bytes {3} [initial] [rendered]
13:54:11 chunk {2} main.e402deade8b026b7d50e.bundle.js (main) 84 bytes {3} [initial] [rendered]
13:54:11 chunk {3} inline.074cdf405b107f2b24b9.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
13:54:11 
13:54:11 ERROR in ng:///var/lib/****/workspace/Build/build_gitlab_angular_app/src/app/components/pages/auctions/auctions.component.html (40,40): 
Property 'fractionSize' does not exist on type 'AuctionsComponent'.
```

Any help with understanding this would make me happy! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number pipe should look more like this:

```
{{ results | number : '1.0-2' }}
```

Where 1 is the minimum number of integer digits; 0 is the minimum number of decimal digits; and 2 is the maximum number of decimal digits.

https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Comment: If you look, you can format it the way I am doing, and that's not the problem. The error is not because of a pipe issue, it's a dependency issue. Thanks though. Using your way causes same error.

Comment: It causes the same error? This error: Property 'fractionSize' does not exist on type 'AuctionsComponent' - that doesn't make sense. If you still need help, maybe show a little more code. The error you have above says it's having trouble finding 'fractionSize.' Why not show your AuctionsComponent file?